Change the size of a single page in a PDF document?
I have a PDF document of an old handbook on the BASIC language. The first page, the cover, is much larger than the rest. When opened in Preview, the result is that the content pages are small and you have to zoom in.
Is there any way to edit just that first page to make it smaller? Everything I've found in Preview seems to apply to the entire document.

Ok, here's how you do it:

Open the document and Show Thumbnails
Select the page in question and Copy it
File->New to make a new document, Paste it
Go to File->Print
Use the Paper Size selection to pick a suitable page size
Use the PDF button at the bottom to save out the page
Open the resulting page to make sure it's correct
If it is, go back to the original document, select the "bad" page in thumbnails, and delete it
Copy the new page into the document by dragging it into the thumbnail area from the Finder

Note that this will result in the page being formatted with margins, which in my case was not correct because the image filled the page right to the edges. If you want to correct this:

In the Paper Size menu select Manage Custom Sizes
Type in the height and width, and then set all the margins to zero


Preview is a very basic PDF editor -- and not even a very good showcase for the features of PDFKit in the OS.
Realistically, you're going to have to make a new PDF of this page, scaled onto a smaller sheet, and then swap the new PDF in.
You might be able to do this in the print menu, using the page scaling and paper size options; or you'll have to 'place' the PDF page onto a page in a graphics app and export from there.
You can drag the thumbnail of this page to the Finder, to make a new PDF of just that page; or duplicate the whole thing and delete all the other pages.

Wouldn't it be simpler to just delete the cover? Easy to do in Preview with thumbnails showing. Then if a cover is needed, make it separately with the same page size as the rest of the manual, and then insert it as the first thumbnail. Really the same as your suggestion but seems like a more direct workflow :-)

@BruceVanAllen Both approaches are replacing the existing page with an adjusted one. If it's a vintage manual, then the cover may have sentimental or aesthetic charm.

@benwiggy - OK, I used thumbnail view to extract the single page to a new PDF in preview. I can see that the page size is about 44 by 63, while the rest of the pages are 17 by 22. Now how do I change the size of the new document? There is an Adjust Size in the Tools menu, but it is greyed out. Anyone know why this may be? I tried select-all but that did not turn it on.
